# Filter dataframe with values from second dataframe

Tags: r

I have two dataframes **a** and **b**.

**a** can be 2000-3000 rows long with 15 columns.

**b** is a small dataframe (2 columns with 150 rows).

Below a simplified dataset.

```
   a <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("ID1", 
    "ID2", "ID3"), class = "factor"), score = structure(c(4L, 5L, 
    3L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("10", "110", "20", "28", "34", 
    "80", "90"), class = "factor"), desc = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), class = "factor", .Label = "text")), .Names = c("ID", 
    "score", "desc"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

  b <- structure(list(ID = structure(1:3, .Label = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3"
), class = "factor"), cutoff = structure(1:3, .Label = c("12", 
"46", "54"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "cutoff"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to filter dataframe **a** using the scores from dataframe **b**. For example in dataframe b the ID "ID1" has a cutoff of 12, so i only want to keep ID1 from dataframe a above or equal to 12. I would like to do this for all IDS.

```
> a
   ID score desc
1 ID1    28 text
2 ID2    34 text
3 ID1    20 text
4 ID3    80 text
5 ID2    90 text
6 ID1    10 text
7 ID3   110 text
> b
   ID cutoff
1 ID1     12
2 ID2     46
3 ID3     54
```

Given the cutoffs in dataframe b the final dataframe a should remain as follows:

```
> a
   ID score desc
1 ID1    28 text
2 ID1    20 text
3 ID3    80 text
4 ID2    90 text
5 ID3   110 text
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is a simple merge and filter problem, see some tutorials. Also, please store numbers as numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following. We first convert the score and cutoff columns to numeric values, since they are now factors. We then subset from the dataframe, using `match` to find the corresponding cutoff from `b` for each entry in `a`.

```
a$score = as.numeric(as.character(a$score))
b$cutoff= as.numeric(as.character(b$cutoff))
subset(a,score>=b$cutoff[match(a$ID,b$ID)])
```

Output:

```
   ID score desc
1 ID1    28 text
3 ID1    20 text
4 ID3    80 text
5 ID2    90 text
7 ID3   110 text
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

with base R:

```
subset(merge(a,b),as.numeric(as.character(score)) > as.numeric(as.character(cutoff)),1:3)
#    ID score desc
# 1 ID1    28 text
# 2 ID1    20 text
# 5 ID2    90 text
# 6 ID3    80 text
# 7 ID3   110 text
```

Or with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
a %>%
  left_join(b) %>%
  filter(as.numeric(as.character(score)) > as.numeric(as.character(cutoff))) %>%
  select(-cutoff)

#    ID score desc
# 1 ID1    28 text
# 2 ID1    20 text
# 3 ID3    80 text
# 4 ID2    90 text
# 5 ID3   110 text
```

Comment: fixed thanks, inserted `as.character` in there

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option:

```
df <- merge(a, b, by="ID")
index <- as.numeric(levels(df$score))[df$score] >
    as.numeric(levels(df$cutoff))[df$cutoff]
df[index, -which(names(df) %in% c("cutoff"))]

   ID score desc
1 ID1    28 text
2 ID1    20 text
5 ID2    90 text
6 ID3    80 text
7 ID3   110 text
```

### Demo

Note: A bit of work converting your factor scores and cutoffs to numeric values.  Unless you plan on having many repeated values, consider using a numeric type to store this information.